# WPF Treeview use property value as Binding Path

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a Treeview using an ObservableCollection of a custom class called MachineComponentFault, which includes a string property called FaultText, and I'd like to make the text localized.

I'm using [WPF Runtime Localization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization#UsingTheCode) from Codeproject to localize texts at runtime, and it usually works as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameInResources, Source={StaticResource Resources}}"/>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to set the value of the property to the path, so that it can retrieve the translation. This is what I managed thus far:

```
  <TreeView Name="myTreeView" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Faults}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MassComponents:MachineComponentFault}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
          <TextBlock Name="Text1" Text="{Binding FaultText}"/>
          <TextBlock Name="Text2" Text="{Binding Path=FLT_PTC_1, Source={StaticResource Resources}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
  </TreeView>
```

Essentially Text1 shows FLT_PTC_1 at Runtime, while Text2 shows "Motor Overheat", which is the value of FLT_PTC_1 in Resources.resx (which can be translated). The issue is that I can't seem to be able to do what Text2 does using FaultText Property.

Is there a way to do it?

EDIT:

Solved it using mm8 solution, while maintaining the WPF Runtime Localization. The solution isn't pretty at all, since it consists in creating a Binding on a dummy class and then retrieving the binding value as a string, which seems a bit convoluted, but it's the best solution I could find.

```
  public class ResourceConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      string resourceName = value as string;

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName)) //look up the resource here:
      {
        Binding b = new Binding(resourceName); //Create Binding using as Path the value of FaultText
        b.Source = CultureResources.ResourceProvider; //Get the resources from WPF Runtime Localization ObjectDataProvider
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(_dummy, Dummy.ValueProperty, b); //Set the Binding to the dummy class instance
        return _dummy.GetValue(Dummy.ValueProperty); //Retrieve the value of the Binding from the dummy class instance and return it
      }

      return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //Initialize Dummy class
    private static readonly Dummy _dummy = new Dummy();

    //Create a dummy class that accepts the Binding
    private class Dummy : DependencyObject
    {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(Dummy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
  }
```

XAML same as mm8 proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the `FaultText` property and use a converter to look up the resource. Something like this:

```
public class ResourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string resourceName = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName)) //look up the resource here:
            return Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Name="Text2">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="FaultText">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:ResourceConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've used the solution in part since the WPF Runtime Localization solution I've found uses ObjectDataProvider to get the Resources and refreshes that every time the language is changed. Do you maybe know of a better method?